# How can I get python tkinter to validate a file path via entry box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on creating a form that will have multiple lines for file path entry with a Browse button next to each entry box. The user should be able to paste a directory path into the entry form and it will validate upon loosing focus that it is an existing folder if it is not change the background to red.

The Browse button may also be used to enter the Folder path and when selecting via the Browse button it will enter the selected path into the appropriate entry box.

Here is the current code I have fairly new to python and complete newb on tkinter gui so trying to teach myself and looking for some guidance

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
from pathlib import Path

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("500x500")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

def browse_path():
    browse_path = fd.askdirectory()
    path.set(browse_path)
    
def enter_Path():
    entry_path = ent1.get()
    if Path(entry_path).is_dir():
        path.set(entry_path)
        return True
    else:
        ent1.config(bg="red")
        return False
        

label1 = tk.Label(root, text = "This is the Label").grid(row = 0)

path = tk.StringVar(root, value = "Enter the first path here")
ent1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = path, validate="focusout", validatecommand="enter_Path")
ent1.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 0, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Browse", command = browse_path).grid(row = 2, column = 1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text = "This is the second label").grid(row = 3)

path2 = tk.StringVar(root, value = "Enter the second path here")
ent2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = path2)
ent2.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 4, column = 0, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Browse", command = browse_path).grid(row = 4, column = 1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could grasp, here is what you can do:

1. `'<FocusOut>'` should be used. This will be if the GUI window has lost focus.
2. `os.path.isdir()`. I am not much familiar with `pathlib`. I have imported `os` module and used `os.path.isdir` to check if it is a file.

Here is a sample program:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import os

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("500x500")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

def browse_path():
    browse_path = fd.askdirectory()
    path.set(browse_path)
def browse_path_2():
    browse_path = fd.askdirectory()
    path2.set(browse_path)
    
def enter_Path(event):
    entry_path = path.get()
    entry_path_2=path2.get()
    if not os.path.isdir(entry_path):
        ent1.config(bg="red")
    else:
        ent1.config(bg="white")
    if not os.path.isdir(entry_path_2):
        ent2.config(bg="red")
    else:
        ent2.config(bg="white")
            

label1 = tk.Label(root, text = "This is the Label").grid(row = 0)

path = tk.StringVar(root, value = "Enter the first path here")
ent1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = path)
ent1.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 2, column = 0, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Browse", command = browse_path).grid(row = 2, column = 1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text = "This is the second label").grid(row = 3)

path2 = tk.StringVar(root, value = "Enter the second path here")
ent2 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = path2)
ent2.grid(padx = 5, pady = 5, row = 4, column = 0, sticky = tk.W + tk.E)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Browse", command = browse_path_2).grid(row = 4, column = 1)
root.bind("<FocusOut>",enter_Path)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Part of this answer includes some bad code. `validatcommand` needs to be a command, not a string.

Comment: Thanks that got me what I needed.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I don't think ```validatecommand``` is even needed